# Repeater Widget - jQuery detect does not work

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, backend, octobercms

The below code works fine with other form element other than "repeater widget" elements in Laravel -> octobercms -> backend ->plugin -> form

```
$(document).ready(function() {

       $('.form-control').on('mouseover',function(){
         alert('hi');
       });

})
```

When I hover over normal input fields in the form, I get the alert message. But when I use add repeater elements that contains input field, mouse over them does not trigger alert.

Kindly help.

Regards

Comment: Please show generated html structure. We have no way to help without a [mcve]. Also do these repeater elements exist at the time the code is run? If not you need event delegation

Comment: I have added the generated html before clicking the "Repeater" add button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). There isn't really enough known as to why your approach isn't working unless the elements are added after your code runs such as through ajax

```
$(document).on('mouseover','.form-control',function(){
     alert('hi');
});
```